# Invalid Stack Traces in Safari with Vite and Vue3

Tags: safari, vuejs3, vite, source-maps

I'm working on a project that my team upgraded from Vue2/Webpack to Vue3/Vite.  We use a crash monitoring tool, Bugsnag, to notify us when a crash occurs.  We've recently noticed that when a crash happens in Safari, the stack traces are completely invalid.  When I reproduce a bug in Chrome or FireFox, the stack traces are correct, but reproducing the same bug in Safari, the stack traces are way off, e.g. they don't even report the correct file.  For example, here is the stack trace for the same bug in Chrome and Safari:

**Chrome**

```
TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') 
    src/components/LayoutInformation.vue:148:46 
    src/components/LayoutInformation.vue:146:21 Proxy.mergedHoleInformation
    node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:167:24 Dh.run
    node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1101:38 get value [as value]
    node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2845:29 Object.get [as mergedHoleInformation]
    src/components/LayoutInformation.vue:15:22 
    node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:850:20 r
    node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6579:54 Jr
    node_modules/@pdga-technology/ui/dist/ui.es.js:809:10
```

**Safari**

```
TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.id') 
    src/components/official/EventHomeTournament.vue:543:48 
    [native code] reduce
    src/components/official/EventHomeTournament.vue:543:48 mergedHoleInformation
    [native code] mergedHoleInformation
    node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:26:22 run
    node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:26:22 value
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 get
    src/components/official/EventHomeTournament.vue:543:48 
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 r
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 Jr
    src/components/elements/OfflineIndicator.vue:4:53 
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 r
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 Jr
    src/components/elements/OfflineIndicator.vue:4:53 
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 r
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 bm
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 De
    node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:26:22 run
    [native code] run
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 Jo
    node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2236:21 BC
    [native code] promiseReactionJob
```

In Safari, the call stack is completely wrong.  For example, the crash above happened in a function named `mergedHoleInformation`, which Safari's stack trace shows, but it shows that function as being in the wrong file (`EventHomeTournament.vue` instead of `LayoutInformation.vue`).  Sometimes the stack traces are so large in Safari that they exceed Bugsnag's limit of 1MB, and we subsequently don't get any notification in Bugsnag whatsoever.  Those same errors in Chrome/FireFox have short stack traces like the one above.

In Safari, I can view the source of our JS files and Vue components and the source *looks* correct to me (that is, Safari seems to interpret the source maps correctly in its developer tools).  I've tried making a small, reproducible example, but have so far failed.  E.g. I've made a small project with Vite/Vue3 and triggered errors in a variety of ways, and the stack traces are always correct.

We don't have much in the way of customization for Vite, mainly just @vitejs/plugin-legacy for legacy browser builds, whitespace preservation in Vue's compiler options, and a few path aliases for images.  The project doesn't have many dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@bugsnag/js": "^7.16.2",
    "@bugsnag/plugin-vue": "^7.16.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.4",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.6",
    "uikit": "^3.12.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.0-beta.29",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
```

I've found these issues that report Safari as showing incorrect line numbers in stack traces, but they're all marked as resolved:

- https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/2550
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=221548
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=235607

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you make a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Duannx I would like to and, as I mentioned above, I have tried: "I've tried making a small, reproducible example, but have so far failed. E.g. I've made a small project with Vite/Vue3 and triggered errors in a variety of ways, and the stack traces are always correct."

Comment: Hi, I'm running into the same issue while developing using Safari. Just posed about it in the vue help on discord and they told me that it works fine in Chrome but not Safari. It's actually easy to reproduce:
`Run npm init vue@latest`
`Choose No for everything except Eslint and prettier`
`ls into the directory and npm install`
`Open HelloWorld.vue and add a throw command at line 5:`
`throw new Error('An Error')`
`npm run dev`